# Double NAT port forwarding with pfSense and subnet - Is it safe?

Tags: networking, security, port-forwarding, nat, vlan

I would like to expose an application server (virtual machine) to the internet for developing/learning purposes. I cannot physically separate my main home network from my server lab. My hypervisor is able to do VLAN tagging on VM network interfaces.

I have installed pfSense on a VM with two virtual network interfaces.

- Interface 1: WAN - main subnet with the ISP router as its default gateway
- Interface 2: LAN - VLAN tagging setup, application subnet, this is the default gateway for the application subnet

Using port forwarding on both the ISP gateway/router and my pfSense virtual machine firewall/router, I am able to connect to my application VM from the internet. Great!

Now, is this at all safe or secure? I am hoping that the VLAN subnet is good enough to protect my smartphones and PCs on the main network in the event that my application server is compromised. I am also hoping that through the use of installed packages on pfSense, I can monitor for suspicious traffic and block IPs based on geography.

[image: Network Diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is reasonably safe, but may not be totally bullet proof.

If there is an issue with your application that allows a compromise, it is possible for that server to then be used as means to get a foothold on your internal server.
Depending on how your Interface 2 is set up it would seem likely that this box would be able to communicate with other devices on the LAN that would be invisible externally - so the security will come down to the security of your application + the security of the firewal between your tagged VLAN and the rest of the network.   (I assume that you don't have firewall rules totally isolating this box from your LAN, as if you did you would not need the VLAN)

Comment: I see what you are saying now. Just having the subnet with vlan setup on the LAN interface of pfsense is not preventing traffic from doing this:

application subnet (vlan, pfsense LAN) --> pfsense WAN (on main network) --> PC on main network

It is interesting (was not obvious to me) that I cannot ping from the main subnet to application subnet, but I can ping from application subnet to main subnet.

Firewall rules it is. Thanks.